# How to access the previous parents in the inheritance hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am just trying to understand if the below is possible.

I have customer, specialCustomer and goldCustomer classes. Special inherits from Customer and GoldCustomer inherits from SpecialCustomer.

How can i access Customer class's implementation of Add() from GoldCustomer? Using base.Add() calls only the immediate parent's Add()

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual void add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Add");

    }
}

public class SpecialCustomer: Customer
{
    public override void add()
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("SPL CUST Add");
    }
}

public class GoldCustomer : SpecialCustomer
{

    public new void add()
    {
        base.add();// cals the immediate parent.
        //How to call the method on Customer base class(Parent's parent)
        Console.WriteLine(" chid GOLD CUST Add");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to avoid such situation if you can (software is complex, why make it even more complicated?).

The second suggestion, if you cannot avoid the situation, is cast `this` to desired base type and call the desired method, like `((Customer)this).add()`

But can you explain why you need to do this kind of thing? It may be that your design needs some refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public virtual void add()
        {
            C1();
        }


        public void C1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Add");
        }
    }
```

Your code should look like this and after that just call `new GoldCustomer.C1();`